# Running go webserver on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: go, webserver, cloud9-ide

im kinda confused on how to run a go lang webserver on Cloud9IDE.. This is my simple go server i am attempting to run:

https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/golangpractice

I tried to click run then went to the url it wants me to go but it told me 404 not found... And i also saw this is the output in the command line when i click run on cloud9:

```
Your code is running at https://golangpractice-amanuel2.c9users.io.
Important: use os.Getenv(PORT) as the port and os.Getenv(IP) as the host in your scripts!

2016/03/14 11:45:51 Listening on port 8080 ...
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

The 404 you're seeing is from line 142 of `webserver.go` so your app actually is running properly. From your code, it looks like you have a route for `/item/name` so try going to `https://golangpractice-amanuel2.c9users.io/item/name` and you'll get something there.

All other routes are giving 404's because of line 142.

Comment: When i go to : https://golangpractice-amanuel2.c9users.io/item/name  , i actually get something.. That is the keys: {"name":"name","what":"item"}  . Now in the html as you can see in the cloud9 says otherwise... Im confused now..

Comment: Can you post what Cloud9 is saying? If you're able to get a response from your server, that means your server is up and running without any problems.

Comment: Thats exactly what it is saying: {"name":"name","what":"item"}  @Mutahhir

Comment: Right, so doesn't that show that your webserver's working? @JohnnyDoe

Comment: @Johnny Doe if you want to html to show up just do /home at the end! Like so: https://golangpractice-amanuel2.c9users.io:8080/home